# Higgs Boson - only little over GCSE physics?

Tags: soft-question, symmetry-breaking, higgs

According to http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/blog/2012/jul/04/higgs-boson-discovered-live-coverage-cern, the reporter says that higgs boson things are little over [GCSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Certificate_of_Secondary_Education) physics. So, English learn a lot about physics in high school? Quantum mechanics is usually learned in university-level courses, right?

By the way, wow. A new particle that looks like Higgs boson.

Comment: It seems like this may be a question more about the English educational system than about physics... is that the case, Higgs Hooray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The science behind Higgs is much more advanced for even undergraduate physics. Most of the physics undergrads dont have enough knowledge to understand this properly. You need to have lot of knowledge in the areas of quantum mechanics, quantum field theory, particle physics usually done at the grad level. Obviously the reporter has been much mistaken. From personal experience I think the UK lags behind in science education. I have had the opportunity to study in UK, India and US, and I am sorry to say the high school education system in UK is the least advanced of the three.